# TypeError: tensor is not a torch image

Tags: python, pytorch

While working through the AI course at Udacity I came across this error during the Transfer Learning section. Here is the code that seems to be causing the trouble:

```
import torch
from torch import nn
from torch import optim
import torch.nn.functional as F
from torchvision import datasets, transforms, models

data_dir = 'filename'

# TODO: Define transforms for the training data and testing data
train_transforms= transforms.Compose([transforms.Resize((224,224)), transforms.Normalize(mean=[0.485, 0.456, 0.406], std=[0.229, 0.224, 0.225]), transforms.ToTensor()])
test_transforms= transforms.Compose([transforms.Resize((224,224)), transforms.Normalize(mean=[0.485, 0.456, 0.406], std=[0.229, 0.224, 0.225]), transforms.ToTensor()])

# Pass transforms in here, then run the next cell to see how the transforms look
train_data = datasets.ImageFolder(data_dir + '/train', transform=train_transforms)
test_data = datasets.ImageFolder(data_dir + '/test', transform=test_transforms)

trainloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(train_data, batch_size=64, shuffle=True)
testloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(test_data, batch_size=32)
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The problem is with the order of the transforms. The `ToTensor` transform should come before the `Normalize` transform, since the latter expects a tensor, but the `Resize` transform returns an image. Correct code with the faulty lines changed:

```
train_transforms = transforms.Compose([
    transforms.Resize((224,224)), 
    transforms.ToTensor(), 
    transforms.Normalize(mean=[0.485, 0.456, 0.406], std=[0.229, 0.224, 0.225])])
test_transforms = transforms.Compose([
    transforms.Resize((224,224)), 
    transforms.ToTensor(), 
    transforms.Normalize(mean=[0.485, 0.456, 0.406], std=[0.229, 0.224, 0.225])])
```

Comment: I did follow this same order and now I am getting: `TypeError: batch must contain tensors, numbers, dicts or lists; found <class 'PIL.PngImagePlugin.PngImageFile'>`

Comment: @Kasparov92 which version of Pytorch are you on?

Answer (score 1):

Another, less elegant solution (assuming the image was loaded with opencv and is hence BGR):

```
t_ = transforms.Compose([transforms.ToPILImage(),
                         transforms.Resize((224,224)),
                         transforms.ToTensor()])

norm_ = transforms.Normalize([103.939, 116.779, 123.68],[1,1,1])
img = 255*t_(img)
img = norm_(img)
```

Answer (score 1):

One reason for this error is that `transforms.Normalize` only accept 3d data (3, 224, 224). Here is an example code:

```
# imagenet normalize

from torchvision.transforms import Normalize

mean = [0.485, 0.456, 0.406]
std = [0.229, 0.224, 0.225]
normalize = Normalize(mean, std)


img = np.random.choice(255, (10, 224, 224, 3))
img = img/255 # [0, 1]
img = torch.tensor(img, device=device).float().permute(0, 3, 1, 2)
img = normalize(img)
```

This will throw the error since the input data has 4d shape. If you change the code to this, then the error will disappear.

```
img = np.random.choice(255, (224, 224, 3))
```

Comment: So, how do I normalize a batch?

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had the problem described in [the comment of shark deng](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60387412/16083419): normalize does not work over a batch.

A solution for me was to use `torchvision.transforms.functional.normalize` instead, which works with batches.